# Application failed codesign verification

Tags: iphone, ipad

When I upload my app to the App store I am facing the issue below:

> Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid,
>   or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate

I did all of the changes below:

- cleaning project,
- cleaning all,
- deleting build directory,
- deleting certificates + profiles
- and reinstall distribution provisional profile and distribuction certificate

but still I am facing the same problem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check that your certificate is correct/valid. To do this, log in to [the iOS Provisioning Portal](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/) with your Apple developer account and create a new distribution certificate. Make sure that you specify that you want to store you app on the iOS App Store. Create a certificate for the App Store by clicking the App Store radio button - don't choose "Ad Hoc". After that, download and install the newly created provisioning certificate.

Check that you've done the following:

1. Set your code-signing identity in the XCode project to use the new provisioning certificate.
2. Used the certificate for Distribution profile, not just Developer.
3. Used the "Clean all targets" function in XCode.
4. Deleted any build folders from your application's directory tree in the Finder.

After that, build and run your application.

For a fuller explanation, see [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG6) about this.

Answer (score 2):

For the iOS error **"Application failed codesign verification"**, see Apple's complete list of potential causes at the following URL ["How do I resolve the error: Application failed codesign verification?"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried all the solutions listed and then some.  But it turned out that it was something so simple, I could kick myself!  Set your Archive Build Configuration to Release.  You can do this by going into PRODUCT -> EDIT SCHEME -> ARCHIVE -> BUILD CONFIGURATION -> SET TO RELEASE.

Good Luck!